# Remove Local Storage JSON Object & Rebuild Array

Tags: javascript, json, object, local-storage

I'm struggling with the task of removing an item from the LocalStorage...here is my LocalStorage data JSON.

```
{
"1461569942024" : 
{"t_id":1461569942024,"t_build_val":"PreBuild1","t_project_val":"18"},
"1461570048166" : 
{"t_id":1461570048166,"t_build_val":"PreBuild2","t_project_val":"17"}
}
```

here is what I was trying to do:

```
function removeItem(array, value) {
    var idx = array.indexOf(value);
    if (idx !== -1) {
        array.splice(idx, 1);
    }
    return array;
}

var newData = removeItem(localStorage['data'], '1461569942024');
```

I would like to remove na object based on object key eg:1461570048166 and re-save whole array again to the LocalStorage.

Thanks

Comment: `delete somevar['1461570048166']`.

Comment: splice is for array and you have an object, use delete instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
var json = {
    "1461569942024": {
        "t_id": 1461569942024,
        "t_build_val": "PreBuild1",
        "t_project_val": "18"
    },
    "1461570048166": {
        "t_id": 1461570048166,
        "t_build_val": "PreBuild2",
        "t_project_val": "17"
    }
};

function deleteItem(input, key) {

    delete input[key];

    return input

}

localStorage.setItem("localStore", JSON.stringify(json));

localStorage.setItem("localStore", JSON.stringify(deleteItem(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("localStore")), '1461570048166')));

JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("localStore"));
```

Comment: What error you are getting. It's working fine, try this fiddle "https://jsfiddle.net/8mc3woa4/2/" just added alert after deleting the key "1461569942024"

Comment: what I have done is..1.) Declaring Json  2.)Storing it in Local storage 3.)Retrieving from Local storage 4.)Deleting one element 5.) storing back to local storage 6.) Again getting data from local storage to check weather the item is really deleted from local storage....Hope that is your requirement too..